# How to read and print this PHP Array

Tags: php, html

I juste want to know how to read and print the value "client_unique_identifier"
 in this PHP array:
this is the library link: http://ts3admin.info
In particular this function: http://ts3admin.info/manual/classts3admin.html#aa73eb538596ef6bd5760a5601a819a69
the output from a library to ts3.

```
  Array
    {
     [cid] => 2
     [client_idle_time] => 4445369
     [client_unique_identifier] => nUixbsq/XakrrmbqU8O30R/D8Gc=
     [client_nickname] => par0noid
     [client_version] => 3.0.9.2 [Build: 1351504843]
     [client_platform] => Windows
     [client_input_muted] => 1
     [client_output_muted] => 1
     [client_outputonly_muted] => 0
     [client_input_hardware] => 1
     [client_output_hardware] => 1
     [client_default_channel] => 
     [client_meta_data] => 
     [client_is_recording] => 0
     [client_version_sign] => ldWL49uDKC3N9uxdgWRMTOzUabc1nBqUiOa+Nal5HvdxJiN4fsTnmmPo5tvglN7WqoVoFfuuKuYq1LzodtEtCg==
     [client_security_hash] => 
     [client_login_name] => 
     [client_database_id] => 2
     [client_channel_group_id] => 5
     [client_servergroups] => 6
     [client_created] => 1361027850
     [client_lastconnected] => 1361027850
     [client_totalconnections] => 1
     [client_away] => 0
     [client_away_message] => 
     [client_type] => 0
     [client_flag_avatar] => 
     [client_talk_power] => 75
     [client_talk_request] => 0
     [client_talk_request_msg] => 
     [client_description] => 
     [client_is_talker] => 0
     [client_month_bytes_uploaded] => 0
     [client_month_bytes_downloaded] => 0
     [client_total_bytes_uploaded] => 0
     [client_total_bytes_downloaded] => 0
     [client_is_priority_speaker] => 0
     [client_nickname_phonetic] => 
     [client_needed_serverquery_view_power] => 75
     [client_default_token] => 
     [client_icon_id] => 0
     [client_is_channel_commander] => 0
     [client_country] => 
     [client_channel_group_inherited_channel_id] => 2
     [client_badges] => Overwolf=0
     [client_base64HashClientUID] => jneilbgomklpfnkjclkoggokfdmdlhnbbpmdpagh
     [connection_filetransfer_bandwidth_sent] => 0
     [connection_filetransfer_bandwidth_received] => 0
     [connection_packets_sent_total] => 12130
     [connection_bytes_sent_total] => 542353
     [connection_packets_received_total] => 12681
     [connection_bytes_received_total] => 592935
     [connection_bandwidth_sent_last_second_total] => 82
     [connection_bandwidth_sent_last_minute_total] => 92
     [connection_bandwidth_received_last_second_total] => 84
     [connection_bandwidth_received_last_minute_total] => 88
     [connection_connected_time] => 5908749
     [connection_client_ip] => 127.0.0.1
    }
```

thanks in advance
Fede

Comment: `echo $arr["client_unique_identifier"]`

Comment: `echo $array['client_unique_identifier']` ?

Comment: Read the PHP documentation page about [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and insist on [how to access array elements using the square brackets syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing).

Answer (score -1):

You can use extract function and use array keys as a variable

Example:

```
$arr = [
  'key1' => 'test1',
  'key2' => 'test2'
];

extract($arr);

echo $key1; // it will print 'test1'
```

Comment: whats wrong in it...please specify so i can improve it..thanks :)